# Trouble with Laravel Validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

This is the code of my Laravel Validator , Whatever I do , The browser responds with "Bye"
What's wrong?

```
public function store()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
    [Input::get('title'),Input::get('body')],
    [Input::get("title") => 'required|min:5',Input::get("body") => 'required|min:5']
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return "Bye";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in this line

```
[Input::get('title'),Input::get('body')]
[Input::get("title") => 'required|min:5',Input::get("body") => 'required|min:5']
```

you are using input field value not input field, so there is no rule attached on value name so replace this with

```
Input::only('title','body')
['title' => 'required|min:5', 'body' => 'required|min:5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You had problems in two parts of your code and this one might work for you.

```
public function store()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        Input::only('title','body'),
        ['title' => 'required|min:5','body' => 'required|min:5']
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return "Bye";
    }
}
```

The problems were in rules

```
[Input::get('title'),Input::get('body')],
```

This is not the way you should pass them, you need an associative array, so you have two options:

```
['title' => Input::get('title'), 'body' => Input::get('body')],
```

or

```
Input::only('title','body'),
```

And you were not passing the fields names, but the input values

```
[Input::get("title") => 'required|min:5',Input::get("body") => 'required|min:5']
```

This would be the way to pass the fields names:

```
['title' => 'required|min:5', 'body' => 'required|min:5']
```